# How to insert data into 2 tables from different database using MYSQL trigger BEFORE with conditions?

Tags: mysql

The code I have doesn't work, I wish to insert data from another table using trigger. Before it inserted, I wish to checking the value is null or not. But when I execute the trigger, it doesn't insert any data.
Here's my code :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `filterNoHP`
BEFORE INSERT ON smsra_sms FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

DECLARE IDx int(11);
DECLARE NumberHP varchar(20);
DECLARE WaktuKirim timestamp;
DECLARE IsiSMS text;

SELECT ID, SenderNumber, ReceivingDateTime,
TextDecoded into IDx, NumberHP, WaktuKirim, IsiSMS FROM ebsms.inbox
WHERE NumberHP in (SELECT NoHP FROM smsra_blokir_number)
and DATE(ReceivingDateTime) = curdate();

IF NumberHP = null then
insert into smsra_sms
set idsms = IDx, SendingDateTime = WaktuKirim, isi = IsiSMS, pengirim = NumberHP
ON duplicate key update idsms = idsms + IDx;

ELSE
insert into smsra_trash
set Nohp = NumberHP
ON duplicate key update Nohp = Nohp + NumberHP;

END IF;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

any idea what's wrong?
Please help, Thank you

Comment: did you enabled the trigger ? : ALTER TRIGGER 'filterNoHP' ENABLE;

Comment: I've tried to enable it and re-execute the code, but it still doesn't work

Comment: when you enter the trigger code do you get any warning ?  if you enable another trigger does it work ?

Comment: I use mysql front and no warning when I execute it